# How to relate multiple same models related_name in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models `Movie` and `Actor`:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(name="name", max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)

class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(name="name", max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name='movie_actor')
```

Now I would like to let the users to add their favourite actors like:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name='user_actor')
```

Now, I would like to make the response for each movie so that the movie can tell that this movie has one/more of their favourite actors or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell if a movie has one or more favorite actors of a given user:

```py
has_favorite_actors = movie.actors.filter(user_actor=user).exists()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filter the Actor objects by the two parameters to get all actors in `your_movie` that are favored by `your_user`.

```
Actor.objects.filter(movie_actor = your_movie, user_actor = your_user)
```

If you just want to check if favored actors exist, add the `exists()` method.

```
Actor.objects.filter(movie_actor = your_movie, user_actor = your_user).exists()
```